# Alfresco: How to see the data of a finished task in the next task?

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I need pass data of a task1 (form of task1) to other task (form of task2), and see this data in the form of task2. I use one aspect for this and I have the next code (a part) for the taskListener (event: complete) in task1:

`execution.setVariable('wf_data1', task.getVariable('wf_data1'));`

In my task2, in the share-config-custom.xml, I have the wf_data1 in the form, but this shows empty.

Why happen this? How to see the wf_data1 in task2?

UPDATE:

The reason of why this not working is which in the file service-context.xml, the redeploy key is "false". I changed this to "true" and all is working.

Greetings,
Arak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to dive into your model and ways of showing it. Alfresco keeps track of the workflow history. I'm not sure till what detail(with/without aspects) is available, but it's quite easy to find out.

With this you can access workflow data in a next task. Just create a custom workflow form controller which retrieves data.

Comment: And where is the workflow history? How can I access for the data of this history?

Comment: And with the /share/page/task-details?taskId=activiti%24start101&referrer=tasks
you can get any task according to it's id.